# Is the Ambient Isotopy relation (for embeddings) symmetric?

Tags: general-topology, knot-theory

**Definition:** Let $X$ and $Y$ be topological spaces. Suppose that $Y$ is compact and Hausdorff.
Let $f,g:X\to Y$ be embeddings. We say that ***$f$ is ambient isotopic to $g$*** (denote $f\sim g$) if there is a continuous function $F:Y\times [0,1]\to Y$ such that the functions of the form $F_t:Y\to Y$, $F_t(y)=F(y,t)$ for $t\in[0,1]$, satisfy the following:

1. $F_t$ is a homeomorphism for all $t\in[0,1]$.
2. $F_0=id_Y$ and $F_1 \circ f=g$.

The map $F$ is called ***the ambient isotopy from $f$ to $g$.***

**Question:** If $f\sim g$, is true that $g\sim f$ ?

I think that the answer is yes, and this is what I have done:

Let $F$ be the ambient isotopy from $f$ to $g$. Consider $G:Y\times [0,1]\to Y$, $G(y,t):=F_t^{-1}(y)$. It is clear that $G$ satisfies conditions 1 and 2 of the definition. How can I prove that $G$ is continuous? I don't know. But here we have some facts:

- Every closed subset in $Y$ is compact.
- If $U\subset Y$, then $G^{-1}(U)=\bigcup_{t\in [0,1]}F_t(U)\times\{t\}$.
- $F(U\times [0,1])=\bigcup_{t\in [0,1]}F_t(U)$, therefore $\pi_1(G^{-1}(U))=F(U\times [0,1])$, where $\pi_1$ is the projection over the first component.

May you give me a hand please?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My previous answer was incorrect, as @Chilote pointed out. Here is the correct answer:
$$G(y,t) = F_1^{-1}(F(y,1-t))
$$
This is continuous and each $G_t(y) = G(t,y)$ is a homeomorphism. Also, 
$$G_0(y) = G(y,0) = F_1^{-1}(F(y,1))=F_1^{-1}(F_1^{\vphantom{-1}}(y))=y
$$
Also, based on the equation $f = F_1^{-1}\circ g$ we have
$$G_1(g(y)) = G(g(y),1) = F_1^{-1}(F(g(y),0)) = F_1^{-1}(g(y)) = f(y)
$$
So to summarize, you don't have to work so hard to "reprove" continuity, you simply use appropriate compositions and inversions so that continuity is obvious.

Comment: To echo Lee's answer in a heuristic way, the map from $f$ to $g$ is a deformation of space (think moving rope). If you start with some rope and move it around, exactly the reverse will get you back to where you started.

Comment: This answer is incorrect! This is not Homotopy. Notice that the function $G$ that you mention does not satisfy the condition 2. $G_0$ is not $id_Y$ necessarily and $G_1\circ g=id_Y\circ g=g$ not $f$.

Comment: @Chilote: oops, you are right, I did not carefully read your definition of ambient isotopy, which is different from the definition that I usually use. I'll take this answer down and think about a better one.

Comment: What happens when $Y$ is not compact or Hausdorff? I was under the impression the notion of ambient isotopy was an equivalence relation on the set of embeddings $X\rightarrow Y$ for general topological spaces $X$ and $Y$. I think now I was wrong..